# how can I configure emacs on Windows to associated with 'open with'?

Tags: windows-7, emacs

I have installed emacs on Windows 7. It works if I go to 'cmd' and type 'emacs'.
But how can I configure it with a specific file extension (e.g. .txt') so that I double click it and it will use 'emacs' to open that file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration):

> Create File Associations
>
> Use Windows command-line commands ‘ftype’ and ‘assoc’:
>
> ```
> ftype txtfile=emacsclientw -na runemacs "%1"
> ftype EmacsLisp=emacsclientw -na runemacs "%1"
> ftype CodeFile=emacsclientw -na runemacs "%1"
> assoc .txt=txtfile
> assoc .text=txtfile
> assoc .log=txtfile
> assoc .el=EmacsLisp
> assoc .c=CodeFile
> assoc .h=CodeFile
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As the above post is rather old and the given solution is said not to be working in [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration), I post the configuration that works for me:

- Create an environment variable `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` set to `<emacs_directory>\bin\runemacs.exe`
- Put this in the emacs init file  : `(server-start)`
- select a file with the type you want to be opened by emacs and use the context menu "Open With..." , then select "More apps" , then select "Look for another app on this PC" and then set to `<emacs_directory>\bin\emacsclientw.exe`

Hope it helps